# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: R$styleable

Tags: android, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

I am migrating an Eclipse project to gradle. After migration I am facing `NoClassDefFoundError` in custom view when trying to retrieve the attr.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myproject.task.R$styleable
com.myproject.task.widgets.TaskTextView.<init>(TaskTextView.java:24)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
Com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.setContentView(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:59)
```

Here is my custom view class

```
public class TaskTextView extends TextView {

    private TypedArray attrArray;

    public TaskTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TaskTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        attrArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TaskTextViewAttr);// app crashes here

    }

    public TaskTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        attrArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TaskTextViewAttr);// app crashes here

    }

}
```

Please help me...

Comment: Did you check in your `attrs.xml` whether `TaskTextViewAttr` is correctly declared? If it is already declared then try clean and re-build the project